# Using Process to connect via mstsc.exe failes

Tags: c#, rdp

I have created a small tool where I want to connect to remote desktop via mstsc.exe.

I found a lot of samples and obviously they all work. But for some reaons my doesnt! :(

Actually its a small code

```
private void RunRDP(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process rdcProcess = new Process();
    //Add/Change Credentials
    /**
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmdkey.exe");
        rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/generic:TERMSRV/{0} /user:{1} /pass:{2}", tbServer.Text, tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);
        rdcProcess.Start();
    */

    //Perform mstsc
    rdcProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe");
    rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/v {0}", tbServer.Text);
    rdcProcess.Start();
}
```

I took out the adding credentials just to test the connection... still fails.

When I comment the line

```
rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/v {0}", tbServer.Text);
```

It at least opens mstsc.exe

In any other case I receive the error

> Invalid connection File

The error must be some like this. Translating this from german to english doesnt bring any similar error descriptions :D

Why does my programm fails ?

Comment: Whats the value of `tbServer`?

Comment: the server name e.g. `myCustomerNumber.myHoster.xyz `... but i delete to much... let me correct this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running 'mstsc /?' gives me:

```
/v:<server[:port]> -- Specifies the remote computer to which you want to connect.
```

So I guess you should change it to:

```
rdcProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/v:{0}", tbServer.Text);
```

Comment: Very strange... i changed it to this.. now it works. I deleted it again and suddenly my posted code works as well... trying around since 1 houre and.... wtf ? :D anyway... it obviously works now....

Comment: That's very strange indeed. Just out of curiosity, what does 'mstsc /?' gives you on your system?

Comment: this gives me the same as yours